# ¿«Living room» en Colombia?

Tags: vocabulario, hispanoamérica, colombia

¿Cuál es el termino preferido en Colombia para «living room»?

O sea cuál o cuáles de estos:

- sala de estar
- salón
- sala
- living
- otro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Colombia al "living room" lo llamamos **la sala**

> Mija, dígale a ese muchacho que entre y recíbale la visita en la sala.

Corta respuesta pero no hay mucho más que agregar.